# Is it a bad practice to move all Doctrine2 Entities into one single Bundle?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Here is my issue; 
Lets say you create a relationship from one bundle to another
(In this case, one user => many notifications)
(UserBundle => NotificationsBundle)

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Gabriel\NotificationsBundle\Entity\Notification", mappedBy="notificationOwner")
 */
private $notifications;
```

The Problem: When the Notificationsbundle gets removed from the AppKernel, the class above gets lost, and the whole application crashes, this wouldn't happen if all entities get moved into the same bundle.
As soon as this relationship exists, you will never be able to disable the bundle again :/

Is there any way to solve this problem "the symfony way"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Symfony Best Practices](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/business-logic.html#using-a-persistence-layer) page recommends storing all entities in your "main" bundle (typically AppBundle) or creating a specific entities folder structure directly in the /src directory.

So either:

`symfony2-project/
├─ ...
└─ src/
   └─ AppBundle/
      └─ Entity/
         ├─ Comment.php
         ├─ Post.php
         └─ User.php`

Or:

> If you're more advanced, you can of course store them under your own
>   namespace in src/.

Strictly speaking, bundles should be completely self-contained and so shouldn't generally be directly referencing another bundle's entities otherwise they become tightly coupled leading to the problem you've encountered.

For private projects (i.e. where you aren't publishing bundles for others to use) it is OK to have multiple tightly coupled bundles, but still entities should all go in the main AppBundle or their own bundle / folder structure as per the above Symfony best practices page.